# Set bootstrap datepicker based on user input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap Datepicker for dates in my application. Everything works fine, but when I try to type in the date automatically in the input field and press enter, it reverts to current date (today) or doesn't select anything. Is there any way I can write the date manually and set the date when pressing enter?

Sorry if this question is answered already, but I couldn't find it nor search exactly.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group test_date">
   <label class="control-label">Date:</label>
   <div class="input-group input-append date" id="contraceptive_test_date_picker">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="contraceptive_test_date" placeholder="aaaa-kk-pp"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#contraceptive_test_date_picker').datepicker({
    endDate: today,
    language: "et",
    weekStart: 1,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    $('#new_confirmation_form').formValidation('revalidateField', 'patient_birthday');
});
```

Comment: Can you test it removing `revalidateField` from `changeDate` handler?

Comment: @VincenzoC doesn't make a difference. As soon as I press enter, it puts blank space there.